# Bad superscript with authblk / xltxtra

Tags: xetex, superscripts, authblk

I'm writing a document using the `article` class using XeLaTeX, and `authblk` to have the author / affiliation displayed using superscript. I also wants to use the package `xltxtra` to typeset better superscripts (for footnotes).

However, when using that last package, I noticed that the superscripts are not typeset correctly in the affiliation anymore. Actually they appear as normal font.

Here is the MWE (with 2 possible work-around commented out):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
% \usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
% \renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
% \makeatother

\title{Bad superscript with authblk / xltxtra}
\author{Author A}
\affil{Affiliation A}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

**First work-around**

As a first work-around (1st commented part above), I noticed I could simply disable the definition of `textsuperscript` in package `xltxtra` by adding option `[no-sscript]`. However I would prefer avoid doing that since I'd like to keep the better superscript in the main text.

**Second work-around**

An alternative work-around (2nd commented part above) is to patch `authblk` by redefining the commands `AB@authnote` and `AB@affilnote` so that to remove the call to `\normalfont`, that is, change

```
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}
```

into

```
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

This works well but this is a patch over a package that is 13 years old, so I guess there is a better solution. Also this patch does not work when using glyphs that do not have 'superior' version (like 'A' or $\dagger$).

**Third work-around**

A last (bad) work-around is to force superscript in math mode, like `\author[$^1]{...}`, but then we might get double superscripting if we select a font without superior glyphs.

.

Any solution that would overcome the limitations of these work-arounds would be appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Indeed the problem disappear if you comment out the font selection. But that's because then you fallback on a font that does not have "superior" glyphes. I have the same problem if I choose 'Palatino Linotype".

Comment: Then the way forward should be to load the font in the correct way, rather than redefining the other package commads...

Comment: @AndrewSwann What do you mean by loading the fond in the correct way? There is no indication that the fonts are loaded incorrectly in the example above.

Answer (score 2):

***Don't load*** `xltxtra`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{Good superscript without xltxtra}
\author{Author A}
\affil{Affiliation A}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `Mapping=tex-text` should be `Ligatures=TeX`, but it's not necessary, for `fontspec` uses the option by default, except for the monospaced font.

---

If the font has real superscripts, but you only know by experiment, you have to redefine `\AB@authnote` and `\AB@affilnote`, because they set `\normalfont`. Probably `\upshape` is the only precaution to keep.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{realscripts}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{\upshape#1}}
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{\upshape#1}}
\makeatother

\title{Good superscript without xltxtra}
\author{Author A}
\affil{Affiliation A}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the point of using xltxtra is exactly to use the superior glyphs instead of using the fall-back scaled down version, which you get in your suggestion above. Of course this is mostly cosmetic.

Comment: @fuujuhi If the font doesn't have the superior glyphs to begin with…

Comment: But it does. If you follow the 2nd workaround above, you can clearly see a difference between the output without xltxtra and with xltxtra. With xltxtra and 2nd work-around, the stem of the font is conserved in the superscript, whereas it is not the case if you don't load xltxtra.

Comment: @fuujuhi OK, but then you need to redefine those `authblk` commands.