# Why can't I combine superscript and small caps in my beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, fonts, superscripts, small-caps

I'm having trouble combining superscript and small caps for an individual word in my Beamer presentation. I haven't found any answers on the topic.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[17pt,t,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setsansfont{brill.ttf}

\setmainfont[
BoldFont=brillb.ttf,
ItalicFont=brilli.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=brillbi.ttf
]{brill.ttf}

\input{pre}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textsuperscript{\textsc{why only small caps?}} this is confusing. \\
\textsc{\textsuperscript{why only small caps?}} this is confusing too.
\textsuperscript{why only small caps?} superscript alone seems to work well.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Remove `xltxtra` and `xunicode`

Comment: @egreg Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is similar to [Bad superscript with authblk / xltxtra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168095/) and the culprit is `xltxtra` that loads `realscripts` which in the case of Brill breaks superscripts, because the font doesn't feature the necessary glyphs.

Just remove `xltxtra` and also `xunicode` that's no longer needed with recent versions of `fontspec.`<sup>1</sup> Just load `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass[17pt,t,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Brill} % or with your call, I have it in my system fonts

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textsuperscript{\textsc{why only small caps?}} this is confusing. \\
\textsc{\textsuperscript{why only small caps?}} this is confusing too.
\textsuperscript{why only small caps?} superscript alone seems to work well.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup><sup>1</sup> The story is long. At the beginning there was `fontspec`, then `xunicode` was released for adding support for characters to be input with commands and `xltxtra` was introduced for easing the loading of both packages; later versions of `fontspec` did load `xunicode`, so `xltxtra` was no longer needed. With more recent releases of `fontspec`, `xunicode` should *not* be loaded. Unfortunately, several templates still load `xltxtra`, which is wrong.</sup>